# Throwable: Unable to locate adb within SDK

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, sdk

I am new to Android development. I have Android Studio running in ubuntu, but when I go to run my first app, it says *"Throwable unable to locate adb"*.

I can't find anything online matching the error I am getting.

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio, Click on 'Tools' on the top tab bar of android studio

Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager >> Launch Standalone Sdk manager

there you can clearly see which platform tool is missing , then just install that and your adb will start working properly.[In Image You Can see every thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qnor.png)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Image Of Dir]It's located in your `sdk/platform-tools` folder

Comment: my sdk folder doesn't contain any platform-tools folder

Answer (score 0):

Click Run on the tool bar, choose Run instead of run app, a pop up will appear in that choose run app, your adb will initialize.